# How to change the format of "Assigned To" field

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We've been working with TFS 2010/VS 2010 pair for quite a long time. The format of the "Assigned To" field was: last_name first_name. A few days ago it suddenly changed to: first_name last_name. Currently when I want to assign a bug I have to type the exact first name (as there are many people sharing the same first name) and at least one letter of the last name. Previously only 2-3 keystrokes allowed me to find the desired person.

Two questions:

1. What could have changed that?
2. How to revert the old format?

Under Project/Team Members the people are listed in first_name last_name format. Unfortunately I can't remember what was the format before the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The value in the Assigned To field is the Display Name of the corresponding account in the Active Directory. So typically your sysadmin made some changes in the Active Directory.
2. As I said it's not a TFS issue, but an Active Directory one.

I'm not expert in AD, but if I remember correctly, the order of the first/last name is changed when you change the regional settings, or something like that.

Comment: It is a field on the Active Directory user account properties pages called Display Name.  Once you change it there then TFS will update its copy of the record in the next synchronization which typically happens hourly.